# Soundproofing cat door

Tags: doors, noise-reduction

We're getting a cat next week and we'd like to place the litter box in the cold room. There is just one catch: there is a super-loud dehumidifier running in that room and it would drive us crazy to hear that noise 24/7.

The noise is inaudible when the door to the cold room is closed, but when it is opened a crack the noise level is bad.

One option we're looking at is to install a cat door instead of leaving the human door open. I am afraid the cat door will reduce the noise insulation properties of the human door.

Another option I was thinking of is installing a spring that would slide the door closed, but I don't want the cat to get locked in the room.

Is there a way to soundproof a cat door so we can all be happy?
Is there an better solution than installing a cat door?

**Update**: I found another option: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=201ITM4ANno. I could leave the door open and cover the crack with acoustic blankets. Based on this video, the noise level should increase by 5 dB instead of 10 dB without the blankets. The cat should be able to step around the "curtain". Downside: this will look ugly.

Comment: a tunnel lined with sound absorbing material may be the way to go, for that to work you'll probably need to put the cat door in a wall.

Comment: Wouldn't the cat have more fun going through a tunnel and back up through the floor?

Comment: The cat may also object to the noise and refuse to use the box in that location as a result.

Comment: @Ecnerwal that's exactly what I was thinking ... I'd strongly suggest to the OP that they try out having the litter box in this room for at least a few days before attempting any soundproofing to ensure that' it's acceptable to the kitty.

Comment: Although not a cat person , we have done similar with dog doors having Great Danes. Labs, and Heelers we have to have a big door, the first thing was teaching the dogs to use the door then adding a second one worked really well like a tunnel that Jason mentioned but it also had the flap on the outside. The only problem we ever had was when I came home one day the Dane was trying to get outside to see me and the lab was trying to come inside to see me and they got stuck in the tunnel it was kind of funny. 
Don’t think cats would have that problem.

Comment: @Jasen The adjoining wall is the foundation of the house (very thick concrete) so we won't be drilling through that :) On the plus side, I've discovered that if I level the dehumidifier the noise level goes down substantially (no more rattling sound). I might be able to leave the door open without losing my mind. Time will tell.

Comment: attaching a tunnel to the door would be tricky, b7uyt yeah making holes in concrete is hard and messy.